# MPI_Comm_size always returns 1 on Code Blocks

Tags: c++, mpi

I followed below tutorial for executing mpi on Codeblocks

[Tutorial for installing MPI on Code blocks](http://zeineddin.blogspot.kr/2012/10/mpich2-on-codeblocks.html)

If I execute simple MPI codes came from Tutorial, I always get 1 for MPI_Comm_size. 
How can I get more threads from below code?

```
#include <iostream>
#include "mpi.h"
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    int  my_rank;       /* rank of process */
    int  noProcesses;   /* number of processes */
    int  nameSize;      /* length of name */

    char computerName[MPI_MAX_PROCESSOR_NAME];

    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv); /*START MPI */

    /*Determines the size of the group associated with a communicator */
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &noProcesses);

    /*Determines the rank of the calling process in the communicator*/
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &my_rank);

    /*Gets the name of the processor*/
    MPI_Get_processor_name(computerName, &nameSize);

    printf("Hello from process %d of %d processor on %s\n", my_rank, noProcesses, computerName);

    MPI_Finalize(); /* EXIT MPI */

    return 0;
}
```

I already tried `mpiexec -n 2 file.exe` on cmd prompt at corresponding location.

But I got an error message `Can't find ~~ __gxx_personality_v0 ~~~ DLL libstdc++-6.dll ~~~.`

---

I solved by renaming other mpiexec.exe file. In my case it was in C:\Program Files\Microsoft MPI\Bin.

Comment: Please move your solution into an answer. You can even accept it afterwards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was caused by another mpiexec.exe in the system path.

So I wrote specific full path in front, such as: "C:\Program Files\MPICH2\bin\mpiexec.exe".

After that renaming another mpiexec.exe file in "C:\Program Files\Microsoft MPI\Bin" to  "C:\Program Files\Microsoft MPI_temp\Bin".

But It gives another error after renaming "smpd version mismatch". So I checked it's version by smpd -version. It was "1.0.3". So I simply re-install smpd by "smpd.exe -install" command.